# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'. ts(2339)

Tags: html, typescript

I have an HTML textarea and when the user types on it, I need to print the character that the user inputs to the console.

So I tried the following code

HTML (`index.html`):

```html
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

TypeScript (`script.ts`):

```
const editor = document.getElementById("editor") as HTMLTextAreaElement;

editor.addEventListener("input", e => {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

This works well as I expected but when compiling this TypeScript code to JavaScript, the compiler gives the following error:

```
script.ts:4:19 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'.

4     console.log(e.data);
                    ~~~~


Found 1 error in script.ts:4
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you say it works well? - how so, are you running your TS code - if so how? - if not: how are you ceratain it works well? and what does it works well mean, it doesn't throw errors, ow it works as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works well when running it in the browser (the HTML code and the compiled JavaScript code).  But when **compiling** I'm getting the above error and I need to make it an error-less compilation. :) @Lord-JulianXLII

Comment: but does it actually produce an output you would expect? or does it just not break everything (because there is a difference between working as you intended (in actually console logging some data)) and just not breaking the whole app)? - so which is it? are you getting meaningful console.logs()?

Comment: As I told you, it works as I expected; It does console.log as I expected. But I get the above error when compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if your event `e` is an instance of `InputEvent` as `InputEvent`s have a `data` property.

```
editor.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (e instanceof InputEvent)
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

Or you can return early:

```
editor.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (!(e instanceof InputEvent))
    return;

  console.log(e.data);
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell typescript, that the `event` is not a generic event, but an input event (because only input events have the property `data`)

So something like this would work:

```
const x = function (event: InputEvent) {console.log(event.data)}
document.getElementById("test")?.addEventListener("input", x)
```

You could probably also achieve that in one line (without the need to decleare x) with the use of Generics and such (but since I'm not yet proficient with them I don't really know how)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it still doesn't work. The compiler gives [this](https://pastebin.com/aMauZbNt) error.

Comment: @UsithaIndeewara I get a 404 Error ... so copy paste the error / (code you changed)

Comment: Thanks, The accepted answer solves my problem. Anyway, this is the right link: https://pastebin.com/aMauZbNt